# Cyrillic in github.com comments

Tags: git, github, encoding, cyrillic

I have a problems with the files of my github repository. The text in Cyrillic is not displayed properly. 
Could I actually enable using cyrillic just for comments? Is it actually a guthub issue?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert all your files to UTF-8, it should solve your problem. GitHub's website understands cyrillic at comments. If it does not correctly show them, maybe tgere is a problem with your client.